# "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed” Error when writing a table into local in R studio

Tags: r, csv

I want to export a table to local drive after decoding a list of geohash.But, when i try to write the file i'm getting the following error,

```
> setwd("D:")
> data<-read.csv('geohash.csv')
> library(geohash)
> data$lat<-gh_decode(data$geohash)
> write.csv(data,"new.csv",row.names = FALSE)
Error in if (inherits(X[[j]], "data.frame") && ncol(xj) > 1L) X[[j]] <- as.matrix(X[[j]]) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

And i'm using the following code to do the same.

```
setwd("D:")
data<-read.csv('geohash.csv')
library(geohash)
data$lat<-gh_decode(data$geohash)
write.csv(data,"new.csv",row.names = FALSE)
```

I'm just starting in R so if anyone can give me an answer that is simple will be better.

Comment: Welcome to SO! How can we reproduce the issue without any data? [mcve] Please read [ask]!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you are writing a suitable data frame. You read in the geohash, but the `gh_decode` returns a vector.  If you have only one geohash, the result will be a vector, not a data frame.  If you have more than one geohash, I'm not immediately sure what you will get back from `gh_decode`.  A reproducible example of your data would help (i.e., `dput(read.csv('geohash.csv')[1:10, ])`; but be careful not to share with the locations of people's homes, for example)

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Thanks for the response, I have a list of geohash and when i decode them I'm getting respective Lat, Lon, Lat-error, lon-error for the respective geohash in the next columns which makes the table data with the following columns,

"geohash,Lat, Lon, Lat-error, lon-error"

But, When i try to export this table i get the above error

tdr1x94
tdr1x88
tdr1x2x
tdr1x2w
tdr1x2t
tdr1rs0
tdr1ry2
tdr1rwr
tdr1ry4
tdr1rvu
tdr1rvs
tdr1rj2
tdr1rj8
tdr1rz7
tdr1rr1
tdr1rqc
tdr1rq0
tdr1rq1
tdr1rmb
tdr1rsb
tdr1rs3
tdr1x9d
tdr1x96
tdr1x93